# Batch file using txt file to move files to another directory

Tags: batch-file, text, move

I have a txt file with the names of the images I want to move to another directory

The batch file runs and I see the following:

`move "c:\sunrise\stock_jpgs\12345.jpg "c:\sunrise\candles-l\"`

but there are no files in the destination folder.
Do I need to include the file name in the destination path?

```
set "FILELIST=C:\sunrise\candles-l.txt"
set "FILESPATH=C:\sunrise\stock_jpgs\"
set "DESTPATH=C:\sunrise\candles-l\"

for /f "delims=" %%X in (' type "%FILELIST%" ') do (
for /r "%FILESPATH%" %%I in (%%X) do echo move "%%I" "%DESTPATH%"
)
pause
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmm... Perhaps you want to change `echo move` to `move`. Just a hunch ;-)

Comment: @dbenham: You should actually post an answer. :-)

Comment: Replace `echo move` To `move`